# As well as the Devil’s Mirror, is Hans from Frozen based on the Prince from the fairytale the Snow Queen?

Tags: disney, frozen

We know that Hans is based on the Devil’s Mirror from the Snow Queen fairytale, and it shows, because he mimics others perfectly.

However, his Disney Wiki says that Hans is also based on the PRINCE from the same fairytale.

So IS he?

Comment: "We know that Hans is based on the Devil’s Mirror from the Snow Queen fairytale" - do we? Who said that?

Comment: Everyone - from the Disney Wiki to SuperCarlinBrothers, to the point where they (SuperCarlinBrothers) did a video about Hans BEING a Mirror.

Comment: Citation needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prince is a minor character in the fairy tale; we learn a little of his backstory from the raven. A princess has declared that she wishes to marry,and sends out a proclamation saying that

> every well-favoured youth was free to go to the palace and converse with the princess, and that whoever should speak in such wise as showed that he felt himself at home, there would be the one the princess would choose for her husband.

However, everyone who turns up at the palace is struck dumb at the sight of the princess, and can only repeat the last word she says. After three days, though, a meanly clad youth with a knapsack turns up; he isn't intimidated by the servants or courtiers, doesn't care that his boots creak loudly, and is able to talk normally with the princess. They decide they like each other a lot, and she chooses him to marry.

So, the similarities with Hans are that he is a stranger who turns up at court, and quickly wins the princess's hand in marriage, despite them not knowing each other for long.

As to Hans' link with the mirror, the scriptwriter said in an interview:

> He’s very talented. He’s charming. He mirrors everyone. And actually the original story had a lot to do with mirrors. And in many iterations of the story we talk about mirrors and we bring them up. And so I held on a little to that, what Hans is is a mirror as a lot of charming, but hallow or sociopathic.

(I think the last sentence has a few typos in the transcript; from here: https://johnaugust.com/2014/scriptnotes-ep-128-frozen-with-jennifer-lee-transcript )

In the original, the wizard's mirror shrank everything good or beautiful reflected in it to almost nothing, but magnified everything ugly or useless. Hans isn't really a great fit for this, as he instead mirrors those around him to fit in and meet his own ends;

> Yeah, exactly. And he mirrors her and he’s goofy with her. He’s a little bit more bold and aggressive with the Duke, because the Duke is a jerk, so he’s a jerk back. And with Elsa he’s a hero.

(from the same interview)

Answer (score 2):

#### Jennifer Lee did say Hans was inspired by the mirror, but there is no evidence he is also based on the prince of “The Snow Queen” - he is more likely based on the archetypal “perfect fairy tale prince”.

Jennifer Lee, the writer and director of Frozen, does say that Hans’s way of interacting with various people is inspired by the mirror in “The Snow Queen”.

> John: But clearly he’s a very talented sociopath.
>
> Jennifer: He’s very talented. He’s charming. He mirrors everyone. And actually the original story had a lot to do with mirrors. And in many iterations of the story we talk about mirrors and we bring them up. And so I held on a little to that, what Hans is is a mirror as a lot of charming, but hallow or sociopathic.
>
> Aline: And she’s also so lonely.
>
> Jennifer: She’s lonely.
>
> Aline: That it’s like she’s falling in love with her reflection in the pond, yeah.
>
> Jennifer: Yeah, exactly. And he mirrors her and he’s goofy with her. He’s a little bit more bold and aggressive with the Duke, because the Duke is a jerk, so he’s a jerk back. And with Elsa he’s a hero. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Scriptnotes, Ep 128: Frozen with Jennifer Lee — Transcript](https://johnaugust.com/2014/scriptnotes-ep-128-frozen-with-jennifer-lee-transcript)*</sup></sub>

However, there is no evidence that he is also inspired by the prince in “The Snow Queen”. The prince is in only one of the seven parts of the story. While Gerda, the main character, is searching for Kay, who has a shard of a troll mirror shard embedded in him that makes him cold-hearted, she hears that Kay might be in a castle. Instead, she meets a princess and a prince who looks somewhat like Kay. They let her rest in the castle, then give her clothes and a carriage to travel in. None of this prince’s story is parallel to Hans’s - the prince *looks* like the boy with the mirror shard in him, but isn’t. However, he does seem to be based partly on the archetypal perfect fairy tale prince and the expected storylines that accompany them.

> John: But I assumed in the second viewing — first off, I was really surprised at the ultimate reveal that he’s a villainess character. But I thought like I must have misremembered. And so then I watched it the second time through and it’s like you gave us nothing.
>
> Jennifer: No, I know. I know.
>
> Aline: But you know what? That is another example of “cake and eat it too,” because the truth is some of those prince/princess romances are creepy. It’s creepy how generic those men are. And it’s creepy how fast the princesses fall for them. And it’s creepy that nobody questions it.
>
> Jennifer: We buy it. Right. Exactly.
>
> Aline: And it is amazing how in those movies often that’s the thing that makes you kind of roll your eyes is like this sort of instant connection. And there is something kind of, you know, if you met those guys there would be something a little too perfect and creepy about them. And so it has that thing where it does exactly what you want the genre to do, but it actually unveils this kind of seamy side to those guys. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Scriptnotes, Ep 128: Frozen with Jennifer Lee — Transcript](https://johnaugust.com/2014/scriptnotes-ep-128-frozen-with-jennifer-lee-transcript)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, Hans is likely not based on the specific prince in “The Snow Queen”, but the archetype of the fairy tale prince in general, in addition to aspects of the mirror in “The Snow Queen”.